# How to read all the contents of a file using read() system call in C

Tags: c, system-calls

I want to read a file using read() system call and copy all its contents to another file. As the input file can be large, I don't know what buffer size to use. How to change the buffer size dynamically? Or is there any other approach like reading a file part by part using a fixed buffer ? Can anyone tell how to do this.

Comment: What should happen if the file size is more than available memory?

Comment: You need only one byte/char as a buffer.  Not efficient, but it would work fine.

Comment: I recommend a buffer size of several kilobytes, maybe 8 to 64 KiB. You may have better performance if it is a multiple of 4096, which is the size of a memory page on most platforms..

Comment: `<stdio.h>` contains a handy macro called `BUFSIZ`, which is the size of the buffer used by `setbuf`. So you can take it as the recommendation from the standard library as to what a good buffer size might be on your system. Unless you have good reason to believe you know more about the subject than the authors of the standard library, just use that for your buffer sizes. (Yes, it's in the C standard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file part-by-part using a fixed buffer. To copy a file, there is no reason why you have to read the entire file in one call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, each time you want to read with a different BUFFER_SIZE, read all the file and copy it to an other one.
I think you can easily read the file using BUFFER_SIZE each time, and join the string to what you've read before until Read returns zero which means end of file(check [read(2) — Linux manual page][1]), than you can write the whole thing to the other file, I hope that this answered your question.